# Load events not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have created razor view in which i have used a master layout in mvc and i want to validate my form on button click but document.ready,window load and jquery function is not working and validate will not work on button click and i dont want to keep my jquery in seperate file so please suggest any solution

```
function ExportPatientDetailServiceConfig() {
    $("#frmExportServiceConfiguration").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var frmData = $('#frmExportServiceConfiguration').serializeArray();
                $.post('/Admin/ExportServiceConfiguration', frmData, function (data) {
                    var result = unescape(data);
                    if (result == "success") {
                        alert('Xml Saved successfully!');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}
```

and my html is

```
<fieldset>
    <legend align="center">Patient Extended Details Service Configuration</legend>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("PatientExtendedDetailServiceConfiguration", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmExportServiceConfiguration" }))
    {
        <table width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Generate Report at :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="ddlHr" name="ddlHr" style="width: 18%">
                            <option id="selectHR">HH</option>
                            @{
                                 for (int i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
                                 {
                                     string ddlHr = "optHr" + i;
                                     <option id="@ddlHr">@i</option>
                                 }
                             }
                             </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>:</span>&nbsp;
                             <select id="ddlminute" name="ddlminute" style="width: 18%">
                                <option id="selectMM">mm</option>
                                @{
                                     for (int i = 1; i <= 60; i++)
                                     {
                                         string ddlMM = "optMM" + i;
                                         <option id="@ddlMM">@i</option>
                                     }
                                 }
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 175px; vertical-align: top">
                            <h2>
                                Clinics :</h2>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label>
                                <input id="chkAllActiveClinics" name="chkSelectClinic" type="radio" tabindex="3" /><span>All
                                    Active</span></label>
                            <label>
                                <input id="chkActiveClinics" checked="checked" name="chkSelectClinic" type="radio"
                                    tabindex="3" /><span>I want to choose Clinics </span>
                            </label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="selector">
                                <ul>
                                    @{
                                         int count = 1;
                                         foreach (TheJoint.Models.Clinic c in (IList<TheJoint.Models.Clinic>)ViewData["Clinic_List"])
                                         {
                                             string checkBoxName = "cCheckbox" + @count;
                                             string spancheckBox = "spCheckbox" + @count;
                                            <li>
                                                <input id="@checkBoxName"  name="ActiveClinic" type="checkbox" tabindex="@count" value="@c.id" />
                                                <span id="@spancheckBox" >@c.name</span>  
                                            </li>
                                            count = count + 1;
                                        }
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h2>
                            FTP :
                        </h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Host :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtFTPServerAddress" name="txtServerAddress" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Username :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtFTPUserId" name="txtUserId" style="width: 200px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Password :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtFTPPassword" name="txtPassword" style="width: 200px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Port :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtFTPPortNo" name="txtFTPPortNo" value="21" style="width: 75px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="button" id="btnCancel" name="btnCancel" value="Cancel" />
                        <input type="button" id="btnExport" name="btnExport" value="Save" onclick="ExportPatientDetailServiceConfig();" />
                        @*<input type="submit" id="btnSaveXml" name="btnSaveXml" value="Save" onclick="ExportPatientDetailServiceConfig();" />*@
                   </td>
               </tr>
               </tbody>
           </table>
           <div id="test">
           </div>
        }
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Why have you put the validation plugin inside a function?  It looks like you're not actually *executing* the validation when you click the button, you're just *applying the plugin* when you click the button.  The examples on the jQuery Validate plugin website don't do this.

Comment: i have tried jquery function also because any event is not firing thats why i have put it in function

Comment: There appears to be a language barrier here, because that statement doesn't really make much sense.  Basically, the call to `.validate()` initializes the plugin, which you want to do when the page first loads.  Not when the form is submitted.  If the JavaScript code is before the markup that it targets, you'll want to wrap it in the jQuery function to wait for the document's load event: `$(function() { // initialize plugin here });`

Comment: it also not work untill or unless load events not fire

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say exactly what's going on, because you've posted code out of context. In general, you want to follow the following principles:

1. Always put your scripts immediately before the closing body tag. Not only is this better for page load speeds, as JavaScript blocks browser rendering, but it also automatically eliminates common problems like trying to attach to an element that hasn't actually been rendered to the page yet.
2. jQuery and other core libraries should be referenced before all other scripts. If you have in page JavaScript, then you should put these references in the `head` element of the page, so that you're assured that they have loaded before that JavaScript runs. However, again, it's better to just move all your JavaScript to immediately before the closing `body` tag, in which case, make sure that jQuery and other core libraries are referenced *before* your custom JavaScript.
3. Pay attention to dependencies. If you're utilizing a jQuery plugin like Validate, then you should reference jQuery *first* and then reference that plugin script. In general, order your JavaScript so that dependencies are referenced before the scripts that depend on them.
4. Always check the developer console in your browser. Chrome has one of the best set of developer tools, though IE's toolset has massively improved in version 11. In Firefox, download the addon, Firebug. While there's more to the browser developers tools than the console, the console is where you'll see things like JavaScript errors. The errors can sometimes be obtuse, in which case, you can bring specific errors here to StackOverflow for help (though, remember to search for existing question, first, before posting your own). If something like `$(document).ready` isn't working, dimes to dollars, there's an error on page. By correcting that error, you'll fix your problem.

Finally, remember that things like `$(document).ready` and `$(window).load` are jQuery functions. As such, you need to make sure jQuery is referenced before you try to call these things.